# Git pushing to GitHub commit without root folder

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, cs50

**Background:** 
I have recently finished Harvard's CS50, and started CS50's Introduction to Game development. Now I am trying to learn to use Git and GitHub to deliver homework. I spent the last 15 days or so learning how git works, and I think I understand the basics. Still, searching on the web, I can't find how to solve an incredibly dumb problem that made me stuck.

**The issue:** 
CS50's team requires you to push your homework to your GitHub repo to a branch called "games50/projects/2018/x/pong". They also require you to NOT change the folder structure (the one that I have downloaded, modified and then pushed, the "Pong" folder you can see below, where I simply modified main.lua).
This means that they will have access to your "main.lua" file to check the work you have done by visiting the following URL : [https://github.com/me50/USERNAME/blob/games50/projects/2018/x/pong/main.lua](https://stackoverflow.com) (where "USERNAME" is your username).

But this is what my branch looks like (Note the second "pong"):
[https://github.com/me50/USERNAME/blob/games50/projects/2018/x/pong/**pong**/main.lua](https://stackoverflow.com)

So it looks like pushing my commit creates a "pong" folder inside the "pong" branch, messing up the required structure and making it unreachable to the CS50's team for evaluation.
I have tried to understand how to submit my files without the root "Pong" folder but completely failed.

**What I have done so far:** 
I am working locally on my computer, with VSCode, on the Main (Master) branch, and have no other branches.

My folder structure looks like this:
`> Pong`
    `| > Sounds`
        `| paddle_hit.wav`
        `| score.wav`
        `| wall_hit.wav`
    `| Ball.lua`
    `| class.lua`
    `| font.ttf`
    `| main.lua`
    `| Paddle.lua`
    `| push.lua`

With Git, I $git init inside VSCode while I have "Pong" folder open as a project folder.
I stage all the files with $git add.
I $git commit the staged files.
I $git push the commit to GitHub.

I get the extra "pong" folder as seen above, containing all the files I wanted to push. I am unable to find a way to get rid of this root folder. I feel stupid.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To move everything out of the root folder you can go to the root directory of your repository and run the following:

```bash
git mv -r pong/* .
rm -rf pong # only run this once you know the files have moved
git commit -am "Collapsed pong directory"
```

Moving the files this way will tell git to preserve the commit history for files instead of assuming you created new files from scratch.